# What the config parameter cacheTokens does on PHPUnit?

Tags: php, phpunit

I was studying the PHPUnit documentation but I could not find a description about the cacheTokens configuration parameter.

I imagine that is something about a generated code, but I have no clue where this is used and what the benefit of turn this parameter on or off.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This attribute configures the in-memory cache of the token streams that are used for code coverage analysis.

When more than one code coverage report is generated in a single run, enabling this cache will increase memory usage and may reduce the time to generate the reports.